# Python Trackback Issue

Tags: python, trackback

When I execute it says Trackback most recent call last  and   line 22 also line 410 in lib and so on with problems within python. Error on home = opener.open() Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File "C:\u\u\d\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace) File "C:/u/u/d/WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2/python-2.7.6/Scripts/ox.py", line 20, in home = opener.open('', data) File "C:\u\u\d\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open response = meth(req, response) File "C:\u\u\d\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs) File "C:\u\u\d\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error return self._call_chain(*args) File "C:\u\u\d\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain result = func(*args) File "C:\u\u\d\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

```
 import urllib
 import urllib2
 import cookielib
 import re
import os
 from random import choice
 cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [
("User-Agent",  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101       Firefox/26.0"), 
("Cookie", ".SECURITY=232")
 ]
f = 58454700
print "", 
 url = 'http://www.myhost.com/increment'
x = 0
while x < 1000000000:
    f = f + 1
    z = str(f)
    url = 'http://www.myhost.com/Send/SentIncrement'
    data = urllib.urlencode({"Increment": z, "VerificationToken": "Verified"})
    home = opener.open('http://www.myhost.com/Send/SentIncrement', data)
    os.system("cls")
    print f
    print data
    x = x + 1
```

raw_input("")

Comment: And which line is that in your code, we can't see the line numbers?

Comment: And what is the type of error. Please provide full traceback in your question. The more detail you give, the easier it will be to understand your problem.

Comment: Added the extra info.

Comment: Its a 500: Internal Server Error, the site either doesn't exist or you are unable to access it. Nothing wrong with your script. I suggest you retag this to a more internet oriented tag.

Comment: The site is up and running though i copied it word for word.